# Enforcing generic interface childs type

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance, interface

I have a generic interface (`MyInterface<T>`), which is implemented by the class `ChildA` in the example below:

```
public interface MyInterface<T>
{
    MyObj<T> GetObj(); // Irrelevant
}

class ChildA : MyInterface<ChildA>
{
    // Irrelevant:
    MyObj<ChildA> GetObj() {
        return new MyObj<ChildA>();
    }
}
```

This works, but I need to make sure that `<T>` always has the type of the *implementing* class, so in this case `T` should always be of type `ChildA`, because it is implemented by `ChildA`.

Another ***correct*** implementation could be this, for example:

```
class ChildB : MyInterface<ChildB> { ... }
```

But currently, this ***incorrect*** implementation is also possible, while it should not be:

```
class ChildA : MyInterface<ChildB> { ... }
```

Is there a way to enforce this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. It is possible to enforce types of itself but there is little to no gain. What's the motivation behind it?

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: @MioBambino I am using this for implementing Data Transfer Objects. It's all working already, but as I mentioned it's still possible to set it as another type. That's why I need to enforce that that cannot happen.

Comment: @Duncan Please describe your scenario in more detail. Your current implementation of DTO has code smell, and we may suggest a better approach if you help us with details.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko I understand that there might be better ways to do this, but I currently don't have the time to change it. I would really appreciate it if someone can tell me if it is possible to implement the given situation.

Comment: How about this approach? `public interface MyInterface { MyObj<MyInterface> GetObj(); }`

Comment: @Duncan Sure, but what does it achieve? If your class already implements the Interface, than you can use the lowest inheritance base.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko With that `MyObj<ChildB> GetObj() { ... }` would still be a valid implementation, wouldn't it?

Comment: This is called the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser/), btw, and no, there isn't a way to add this restriction in C#. To quote @EricLippert, *"[the template] seems like an abuse of a mechanism rather than the modeling of a concept from the program’s “business domain”*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot enforce a generic type argument to be constrained to the implementing type.

The available [**type constraints**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) are the following:

- `where T : struct`
- `where T : class`
- `where T : new()`
- `where T : <base class name>`
- `where T : <interface name>`
- `where T : U`

There is nothing like `where T : self` in C#. Actually, it wouldn't even make sense, because such a thing cannot be meaningfully enforced. Besides, it wouldn't fit at all into the covariance/contravariance concepts and would be weird to inherit from, in general.

The closest thing you can do is this:

```
public interface IMyInterface<T> where T : IMyInterface<T>
{
    MyObj<T> GetObj();
}
```

## Why it wouldn't make sense

Let's say you could do this:

```
public interface IMyInterface<T> where T : self // this syntax does not exist in C#
{
    MyObj<T> GetObj();
}
```

Now all implementing types would have to use themselves as the type argument. But you could still do this:

```
public class ChildC<T> : IMyInterface<T> where T : self
{
    /* ... */
}
```

Which would go around your restriction.

Comment: Wouldn't the last declaration also require `where T : self` in order to compile?

Comment: @Groo Probably :) Depending on how the language authors would want it to work.

Comment: Right now you need to add the restriction to the generic class too, so with the hypothetical `"self"` constraint being applied in the same manner, it would most likely work properly with the class. It would also probably requeire making the class `sealed`, if I am right, since you wouldn't be able to derive from it "legally".

Comment: @Groo OK, added the constraint.

Comment: Well, if the hypothetical `self` mean the declarator of the constraint OR his children, that still make sense to me. Because the declarator only, doesn't make sense for sure. Am I right ?

Comment: @romain-aga Well, to me it wouldn't make much sense either way, to be honest :(

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to enforce this?

Well, not with generic constraints. You can do that with reflection though i'd vote against it :

```
public abstract class BaseChild<T> : MyInterface<T>
{
    protected BaseChild()
    {
        if (typeof(T) != this.GetType())
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format(
                          "Type {0} is not supported as valid type parameter for type {1}",
                             typeof(T).Name, this.GetType().Name));
        }
    }
}
```

Example :

```
class ChildA : BaseChild<int> { }

// Bang! throws
var instance = new ChildA();
```

.

```
class ChildB : BaseChild<ChildB> { }

// Ok here
var instance = new ChildB();
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this but you can create your own control comparing the generic type of the interface and the type of your class. See the example:

```
class ChildA : MyInterface<ChildB>
{
    public ChildA()
    {
        this.ValidateGenericType();
    }

    public MyObj<ChildB> GetObj()
    {
        return new MyObj<ChildB>();
    }

    protected void ValidateGenericType()
    {
        //throws an Exception because ChildB is different of ChilA
        if (this.GetType().Name != this.GetType().GetInterfaces()[0].GetGenericArguments()[0].Name)
        {
            throw new Exception("The generic type must be of type ChildA.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you should use extension methods instead of enforcing some interface for this purpose

```
public interface ISomeInterface {}

public class Child: ISomeInterface {}

public class OtherChild : ISomeInterface { }

public static class MyInterfaceExtensions
{
    public static MyObj<T> GetMyObj<T>(this T child) where T : ISomeInterface
    {
        return new MyObj<T>();
    }
}

public static class Test
{
    public static void RunTest()
    {
        var child = new Child();
        var otherChild = new OtherChild();

        MyObj<Child> myObj = child.GetMyObj();
        MyObj<OtherChild> myOtherObj = otherChild.GetMyObj();
    }
}
```